# Is there an R function to compare between 1 column value with all values of another column?

Tags: r, time, time-series, comparison, multiple-columns

I am working with two different large data set and trying to make use of mapply() to get iterative functions working.

The goal is to take each data point column wise from column 'a', and compare it against all the data points in column'b'. If one element from 'a' is greater than any element of 'b' then  'compar' column is 'YES'.
df<-data.frame('a'=c(10,15,8),'b'=c(22,11,9))

```
and I want the output to be something like this:

   a  b compar
1 10 22    yes
2 15 11    yes
3  8  9     no
```

Comment: `df$compar <- c('no', 'yes')[(df$col1 > df$col2) + 1]`

Comment: I got this error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, compar, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df=data.frame(
   col1=c('2001-06-30 01:00:00','2001-07-01 01:00:00','2000-07-01 01:00:00'),
   col2=c('2000-08-01 01:00:00','2003-07-01 01:00:00','2004-06-30 01:00:00')
)

df <- df %>%
 #format dates
 mutate_at(c('col1','col2'), ~ymd_hms(.)) %>%
 #add the new column
 mutate(compar = case_when(col1 > col2 ~ 'yes', TRUE ~ 'no'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df$compar <- c('no', 'yes')[(df$a > df$b) + 1]
```

Or

```
df$compar <- ifelse(df$a > df$b, "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a working example of your original post.

```
col1 <- c(as.Date("2001-06-30 01:00:00 UTC"),as.Date("2001-07-01 01:00:00 UTC"),as.Date("2000-07-01 01:00:00 UTC"))
col2 <- c(as.Date("2000-08-01 01:00:00 UTC"),as.Date("2003-07-01 01:00:00 UTC"),as.Date("2004-06-30 01:00:00 UTC"))
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
df

check <- function(elem, datafr){

  if (TRUE %in% (elem > datafr$col2)) {
    return (TRUE)
  }
  else {
    return (FALSE)
  }
}

addCol3 <- function(vector, dframe) {
  vr <- c() ### an empty vector 

  for (i in 1:length(vector)) { 
    vr[i] <- check(vector[i], dframe)
  }
  return (vr)
}

df$col3 <- addCol3(df$col1, df)
df
```